# Casting to Collection<interface>

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, collections, casting

With this:

```
public class Widget : IWidget {}
```

Why does `collection2 == null` here:

```
var collection1 = collectionView.SourceCollection as ObservableCollection<Widget>;
var collection2 = collectionView.SourceCollection as ObservableCollection<IWidget>;
```

Where `SourceCollection is ObservableCollection<Widget>`

Comment: what is the type of SourceCollection

Comment: And collection 1 isn't? What is the type of collectionView.SourceCollection before you try to cast?

Comment: If you are using .NET 4, read this: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? Version 4.0 normally supports generic covariance.

Comment: You could use the LINQ `Cast()` method - but look into covariance first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the collection is declared as `ObservableCollection<Widget>` it cannot be cast to `ObservableCollection<IWidget>`. <s>I believe this is possible in .NET 4 but not 3.5 or less</s> - CORRECTION - refer Adam's comment below.

For the above to work you must declare the list as `ObservableCollection<IWidget>` then both casts will work. You should always use the interface type where possible anyway.

As an aside when you use the 'as' keyword this is called safe casting. It will return null if the cast is not possible. Explicit casting ... ie `(ObservableCollection<IWidget>) collectionView.SourceCollection` will throw an exception if the cast is not possible.

Comment: No, this is not possible in any version of .NET. Covariance and contravariance are available *only* on interface types (`ObservableCollection is a concrete type), and only in certain cases.

Comment: @AdamRobinson .. I wasn't 100% sure ... thanks for the comment. Have updated answer to suit :)